# Cyclic reference of RefCell borrows in traversal

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, lifetime, borrowing, interior-mutability

I'm learning Rust and tried coding a doubly-linked list. However, I'm stuck already at a typical iterative traversal implementation. I'm getting the impression that the borrow checker / drop checker is too strict and cannot infer the correct lifetime for the borrow when it crosses the function boundary from `RefCell`. I need to repeatedly set a variable binding (`curr` in this case) to the borrow of its current contents:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Rc<RefCell<LinkedNode<T>>>>,
    // ...
}

struct LinkedNode<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<LinkedNode<T>>>>,
    // ...
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T, idx: usize) -> &mut LinkedList<T> {
        // ... some logic ...

        // This is the traversal that fails to compile.
        let mut curr = self.head.as_ref().unwrap();
        for _ in 1..idx {
            curr = curr.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap()
        }

        // I want to use curr here.
        // ...
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

**Without NLL**

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:22:20
   |
22 |             curr = curr.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap()
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
23 |         }
   |         - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
...
28 |     }
   |     - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

**With NLL**

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:22:20
   |
22 |             curr = curr.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap()
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                    |
   |                    creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                    a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
23 |         }
   |         -
   |         |
   |         temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |         ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::cell::Ref<'_, LinkedNode<T>>`
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
   = note: The temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block. Consider adding semicolon after the expression so its temporaries are dropped sooner, before the local variables declared by the block are dropped.
```

I would really appreciate a **iterative solution** (*non-recursive*) to this problem.

Comment: Note: the borrow checker is not too strict, it prevents aliasing to occur here. If not for this, you could have mutability + aliasing, and thus crashes or memory corruption.

Comment: @MatthieuM. where would aliasing occur here?

Comment: Have you had an opportunity to read [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/)?

Comment: @Shepmaster: If you can get `curr` without borrowing `self`, what prevents you from getting `curr` again in the same method body? Nothing. This is dynamically prevented by getting `RefCell::borrow` to only lend references valid during the lifetime of its result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone `Rc` to avoid lifetime issues:

```
let mut curr = self.head.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
for _ in 1..idx {
    let t = curr.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
    curr = t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However, when I need to borrow mut from `curr` in the following lines, I had to do
`let next = curr.borrow_mut().next.take(); match next {...}`
instead of simply
`match curr.borrow_mut().next.take() {...}`. The compiler doesn't try hard to infer things eh.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a smaller reproduction that I believe shows the same problem:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let foo = RefCell::new(Some(42));
    let x = foo.borrow().as_ref().unwrap();
}
```

As I read it:

1. `foo.borrow()` returns a [`cell::Ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html), a type of *smart pointer*. In this case, the smart pointer acts like an `&Option<i32>`.
2. `as_ref()` creates an `Option<&i32>` where the inner reference has the same lifetime as the smart pointer.
3. The `Option` is discarded, yielding only an `&i32`, still with a lifetime of the smart pointer.

Notably, the smart pointer `Ref` only lasts for the statement, but the code attempts to return a reference into the `Ref` that would outlive the statement.

Generally, the solution would be to do something like this:

```
let foo_borrow = foo.borrow();
let x = foo_borrow.as_ref().unwrap();
```

This keeps the smart pointer around longer, allowing the lifetime of the reference to be valid for as long as `foo_borrow` (representing the borrow itself) exists.

In the case of a loop, there's not much you can do, as you essentially want to borrow every previous node until you get to the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you saying that there is no way to do this in a loop? I'm not sure if your example is a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Tsukki I wouldn't say no way, but **I** don't know it. When you do it recursively, I assume that there is an implicit hierarchy of outstanding borrows that allows it to proceed.